# Is there any cause for a scala print statement working outside of a for loop but not inside a for loop?

Tags: scala, for-loop, printing

In this statement "Hi World!" prints, however "Hello World!" does not.
I have tried researching for loops and print statements but could find nothing which would suggest to me why this code is failing.

"fileNames" is defined in the code elsewhere and displays no errors.

```
def parseSecondDataSource() = 
{
    println("hi world!")
    for (fileName <- fileNames)
    {
      var jsonColumn: Array[String] = Array{""}
      var columnName: String = ""
      println("hello world!")

      //Loads the JSON file
val jsonFile: Iterator[String] = scala.io.Source.fromFile("\Path\To\File" +fileName).getLines()

      println(jsonFile.size)
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked if fileNames is empty?

Comment: Thats probably it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the `for` loop will only execute if `fileNames` is `nonEmpty`, otherwise it will be skipped and no output will be generated from inside the loop.